# Getting server info

Tags: aem

I'm looking to write some code that pulls from an external source.  On our build/qa environment, I want it to hit a different source then production.  Just need a way to identify the servers name.  Similar to currentPage.getName(), but more like currentServer.getName().

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean, but how about an OSGi Service where you configure the source on each environment differently. You can even have run mode specific configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the limited info.  I'm not a java developer.  Here's what i've found.

Using this I was able to get a list of the available environment variables.

```
<%
Map<String, String> envMap = System.getenv();
SortedMap<String, String> sortedEnvMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(envMap);
Set<String> keySet = sortedEnvMap.keySet();
for (String key : keySet) {
    String value = envMap.get(key);
    %><%=key%>: <%=value%><br><%
}
%>
```

That led me to this bit of code.

```
String server = System.getenv("HOSTNAME");
```